# How to install Python3.6 in Google Colab?

Tags: python, pyspark, installation, google-colaboratory, python-3.6

I want to install the spark-privacy-preserve module in Colab. The prerequisite for this module is python3.6 or python3.7 and pip=20.0.2. I used the following code to install python3.6 in Colab:

```
# Install python 3.6 on colab
!python --version
!sudo apt-get update -y
!sudo apt-get install python3.6
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 1
```

But the following error appears:

[image: Error: alternative path /user/bin/python3.6 doesn't exist.]

I've searched the internet but couldn't find a clear answer for this issue. Can anyone help me?